# iOS Push Notification SSL Certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, server-side, apple-push-notifications

Is the certificate generated to send push notifications specific to the server, or I can use it on any other server, if I change my server?

Thank you.

Comment: No I don't think the certificate is server specific.

Comment: generally, one certificate is for 1 domain. So if the other server is also in the same domain, you can use the same certificate. Otherwise, you need to create another cert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it in any server. Apple push notification SSL certificate is not specific to any server.

Example: parse.com, xtify.com etc.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use it on any server -- its the certificate and its corresponding private key that matters, not the IP from which the connection is made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in any server. Apple push notification SSL certificate is not specific to any server.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.