# Questions about iOS Push

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm wondering two questions about iOS Push notifications :

- I'm managing in-house apps that I send to lot of people.  Is it possible to enable push notifications without a fixed app id ? Actually, I have an app id for all my apps (which looks like com.company.*) in order to not create an id for each app.
  My aim is to make my in-house apps able to receive push notifications :)
- Can we use a generated iOS SSL certificate for other use or is it created specifically for iOS Push ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcard App ID is not applicable for Game Center, Apple Push Notification Service (APNS), In-App Purchase (IAP), Data Protection, and iCloud.

**Conclusion:** Explicit App ID has to be used.

From Apple's Provisioning Portal documentation:

> An App ID is the combination of a unique ten character string called
>   the "Bundle Seed ID" and a traditional CF Bundle ID (or Bundle
>   Identifier). The Bundle Seed ID portion of your App ID can be utilized
>   to share keychain access between multiple applications you build with
>   a single App ID. In addition, it can be incorporated into any external
>   hardware accessories you wish to pair your iOS application with.
>   Registration of your App ID is required to utilize the Apple Push
>   Notification service (APNs) and to register an application to
>   incorporate In App Purchases.
>
> The Bundle Identifier portion of an App ID can be substituted with a
>   wild-card character (asterisk '*') so that a single App ID may be used
>   to build and install multiple applications. If the wild-card character
>   is not used, the Bundle Identifier portion of your App ID must be
>   input as your CF Bundle ID in Xcode to allow the application to
>   install on your device. The Bundle Seed ID portion of your App ID does
>   not need to be input into Xcode. Wild-card App IDs cannot be used with
>   the Apple Push Notification service or for In App Purchase.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help me for the second one ?

Comment: I think this answers your second question exactly - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473610/ios-push-notification-ssl-certificate

Comment: @Seb, the certificate is usable in ANY server, as long as OpenSSL is installed and able to connect to Apple's APNS server.

Comment: My question isn't : can I use the SSL certificate on all the server ?
My question is : can I use the SSL certificate for an other use and not only for the iOS push notifications ?

Comment: please study certificate architecture. certificate is to verify identity against a certificate authority you request the certificate from. If you request a certificate against Amazon, you can use the certificate in the progress of verification of identity of Amazon service. Thus, the answer of your question is, the SAME certificate cannot be used in other service other than the server you are requesting server from (i.e. the APNS server )